# Unable to connect more than one device on raspberry pi 4 hotspot

Tags: wifi, pi-4, ubuntu, hostapd, systemd-networkd

I am trying to configure raspberry pi wifi module as AP and client at the same time on same wlan0 interface using [Access point as WiFi router/repeater, optional with bridge](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/89803/access-point-as-wifi-router-repeater-optional-with-bridge) this tutorial, the problem I am facing is that only one device gets connected to AP, if I try to connect second device the device goes to connected-disconnected-than continues saved state and do not gets connect. only the device which comes first gets connected none other, I have googled a lot but failed to find any solution.
My files Configurations and logs are.

```
interface=ap@wlan0
#driver=nl80211
#ieee80211n=1
driver=nl80211
country_code=DE
ssid=embabcd
hw_mode=g
channel=11
wmm_enabled=1
#macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=12345678emb
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP CCMP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP

bridge=br0
```

ifconfig

```
ifconfig
ap@wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::e65f:1ff:fe90:f845  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether e4:5f:01:90:f8:45  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1689  bytes 393516 (393.5 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1764  bytes 1085357 (1.0 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.4.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.4.255
        inet6 fe80::8069:27ff:fe56:1537  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 82:69:27:56:15:37  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1852  bytes 416581 (416.5 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1794  bytes 1047295 (1.0 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether e4:5f:01:90:f8:44  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 84  bytes 6160 (6.1 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 84  bytes 6160 (6.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.195  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::e65f:1ff:fe90:f845  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether e4:5f:01:90:f8:45  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 16375  bytes 12419366 (12.4 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 14483  bytes 2763990 (2.7 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

log of accesspoint@wlan0

```
journalctl --follow -u accesspoint@wlan0
Sep 16 15:06:13 rizvi hostapd[5672]: ap@wlan0: AP-ENABLED
Sep 16 15:07:26 rizvi hostapd[5672]: ap@wlan0: STA fe:6e:77:be:8e:f2 IEEE 802.11: associated
Sep 16 15:07:26 rizvi hostapd[5672]: ap@wlan0: STA fe:6e:77:be:8e:f2 IEEE 802.11: associated
Sep 16 15:07:26 rizvi hostapd[5672]: ap@wlan0: AP-STA-POSSIBLE-PSK-MISMATCH fe:6e:77:be:8e:f2
Sep 16 15:07:28 rizvi hostapd[5672]: ap@wlan0: AP-STA-CONNECTED fe:6e:77:be:8e:f2
Sep 16 15:07:28 rizvi hostapd[5672]: ap@wlan0: STA fe:6e:77:be:8e:f2 RADIUS: starting accounting session CB5A7D34A8890A4B
Sep 16 15:07:28 rizvi hostapd[5672]: ap@wlan0: STA fe:6e:77:be:8e:f2 WPA: pairwise key handshake completed (RSN)
Sep 16 15:07:28 rizvi hostapd[5672]: ap@wlan0: EAPOL-4WAY-HS-COMPLETED fe:6e:77:be:8e:f2
Sep 16 15:07:28 rizvi hostapd[5672]: ap@wlan0: STA fe:6e:77:be:8e:f2 RADIUS: starting accounting session CB5A7D34A8890A4B
Sep 16 15:07:28 rizvi hostapd[5672]: ap@wlan0: STA fe:6e:77:be:8e:f2 WPA: pairwise key handshake completed (RSN)
Sep 16 15:32:11 rizvi hostapd[5672]: ap@wlan0: interface state ENABLED->DISABLED
Sep 16 15:32:11 rizvi hostapd[5672]: ap@wlan0: AP-STA-DISCONNECTED fe:6e:77:be:8e:f2
Sep 16 15:32:11 rizvi systemd[1]: Stopping accesspoint with hostapd (interface-specific version)...
Sep 16 15:32:11 rizvi hostapd[5672]: ap@wlan0: AP-DISABLED
Sep 16 15:32:11 rizvi hostapd[5672]: ap@wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-TERMINATING
Sep 16 15:32:11 rizvi hostapd[5672]: nl80211: deinit ifname=ap@wlan0 disabled_11b_rates=0
Sep 16 15:32:12 rizvi systemd[1]: accesspoint@wlan0.service: Deactivated successfully.
Sep 16 15:32:12 rizvi systemd[1]: Stopped accesspoint with hostapd (interface-specific version).
Sep 16 15:32:12 rizvi systemd[1]: Starting accesspoint with hostapd (interface-specific version)...
Sep 16 15:32:12 rizvi systemd[1]: Started accesspoint with hostapd (interface-specific version).
Sep 16 15:32:12 rizvi hostapd[7264]: nl80211: kernel reports: Match already configured
Sep 16 15:32:12 rizvi hostapd[7264]: nl80211: kernel reports: Match already configured
Sep 16 15:32:12 rizvi hostapd[7264]: nl80211: kernel reports: Match already configured
Sep 16 15:32:12 rizvi hostapd[7264]: nl80211: kernel reports: Match already configured
Sep 16 15:32:12 rizvi hostapd[7264]: nl80211: kernel reports: Match already configured
Sep 16 15:32:12 rizvi hostapd[7264]: nl80211: kernel reports: Match already configured
Sep 16 15:32:12 rizvi hostapd[7264]: nl80211: kernel reports: Match already configured
Sep 16 15:32:12 rizvi hostapd[7264]: nl80211: kernel reports: Match already configured
Sep 16 15:32:12 rizvi hostapd[7264]: nl80211: kernel reports: Match already configured
Sep 16 15:32:12 rizvi hostapd[7264]: nl80211: kernel reports: Match already configured
Sep 16 15:32:12 rizvi hostapd[7264]: nl80211: kernel reports: Match already configured
Sep 16 15:32:12 rizvi hostapd[7264]: nl80211: kernel reports: Match already configured
Sep 16 15:32:12 rizvi hostapd[7264]: ap@wlan0: interface state UNINITIALIZED->COUNTRY_UPDATE
Sep 16 15:32:12 rizvi hostapd[7264]: ap@wlan0: interface state COUNTRY_UPDATE->ENABLED
Sep 16 15:32:12 rizvi hostapd[7264]: ap@wlan0: AP-ENABLED
Sep 16 15:32:44 rizvi hostapd[7264]: ap@wlan0: STA fe:6e:77:be:8e:f2 IEEE 802.11: associated
Sep 16 15:32:44 rizvi hostapd[7264]: ap@wlan0: STA fe:6e:77:be:8e:f2 IEEE 802.11: associated
Sep 16 15:32:45 rizvi hostapd[7264]: ap@wlan0: STA fe:6e:77:be:8e:f2 WPA: received EAPOL-Key msg 2/4 in invalid state (10) - dropped
Sep 16 15:32:45 rizvi hostapd[7264]: ap@wlan0: STA fe:6e:77:be:8e:f2 WPA: received EAPOL-Key msg 2/4 in invalid state (10) - dropped
Sep 16 15:32:48 rizvi hostapd[7264]: ap@wlan0: STA fe:6e:77:be:8e:f2 IEEE 802.11: disassociated
Sep 16 15:32:48 rizvi hostapd[7264]: ap@wlan0: STA fe:6e:77:be:8e:f2 IEEE 802.11: disassociated
Sep 16 15:32:48 rizvi hostapd[7264]: ap@wlan0: STA fe:6e:77:be:8e:f2 IEEE 802.11: disassociated
Sep 16 15:32:48 rizvi hostapd[7264]: ap@wlan0: STA fe:6e:77:be:8e:f2 IEEE 802.11: disassociated
Sep 16 15:32:50 rizvi hostapd[7264]: ap@wlan0: STA fe:6e:77:be:8e:f2 IEEE 802.11: associated
Sep 16 15:32:50 rizvi hostapd[7264]: ap@wlan0: STA fe:6e:77:be:8e:f2 IEEE 802.11: associated
Sep 16 15:32:50 rizvi hostapd[7264]: ap@wlan0: AP-STA-CONNECTED fe:6e:77:be:8e:f2
Sep 16 15:32:50 rizvi hostapd[7264]: ap@wlan0: STA fe:6e:77:be:8e:f2 RADIUS: starting accounting session D054B04CBB8D0AEB
Sep 16 15:32:50 rizvi hostapd[7264]: ap@wlan0: STA fe:6e:77:be:8e:f2 WPA: pairwise key handshake completed (RSN)
Sep 16 15:32:50 rizvi hostapd[7264]: ap@wlan0: EAPOL-4WAY-HS-COMPLETED fe:6e:77:be:8e:f2
Sep 16 15:32:50 rizvi hostapd[7264]: ap@wlan0: STA fe:6e:77:be:8e:f2 RADIUS: starting accounting session D054B04CBB8D0AEB
Sep 16 15:32:50 rizvi hostapd[7264]: ap@wlan0: STA fe:6e:77:be:8e:f2 WPA: pairwise key handshake completed (RSN)
```

logs of hostapd.conf

```
journalctl --follow -u hostapd.service
Sep 16 15:07:26 rizvi hostapd[5779]: ap@wlan0: STA fe:6e:77:be:8e:f2 WPA: pairwise key handshake completed (RSN)
Sep 16 15:32:11 rizvi hostapd[5779]: ap@wlan0: STA fe:6e:77:be:8e:f2 IEEE 802.11: disassociated
Sep 16 15:32:17 rizvi systemd[1]: Stopping Access point and authentication server for Wi-Fi and Ethernet...
Sep 16 15:32:17 rizvi systemd[1]: hostapd.service: Deactivated successfully.
Sep 16 15:32:17 rizvi systemd[1]: Stopped Access point and authentication server for Wi-Fi and Ethernet.
Sep 16 15:32:17 rizvi systemd[1]: Starting Access point and authentication server for Wi-Fi and Ethernet...
Sep 16 15:32:17 rizvi hostapd[7380]: ap@wlan0: interface state UNINITIALIZED->COUNTRY_UPDATE
Sep 16 15:32:17 rizvi hostapd[7380]: ap@wlan0: interface state COUNTRY_UPDATE->ENABLED
Sep 16 15:32:17 rizvi hostapd[7380]: ap@wlan0: AP-ENABLED
Sep 16 15:32:17 rizvi systemd[1]: Started Access point and authentication server for Wi-Fi and Ethernet.
Sep 16 15:32:44 rizvi hostapd[7381]: ap@wlan0: STA fe:6e:77:be:8e:f2 IEEE 802.11: associated
Sep 16 15:32:45 rizvi hostapd[7381]: ap@wlan0: STA fe:6e:77:be:8e:f2 RADIUS: starting accounting session 4903A63C880CEF5D
Sep 16 15:32:45 rizvi hostapd[7381]: ap@wlan0: STA fe:6e:77:be:8e:f2 WPA: pairwise key handshake completed (RSN)
Sep 16 15:32:48 rizvi hostapd[7381]: ap@wlan0: STA fe:6e:77:be:8e:f2 IEEE 802.11: disassociated
Sep 16 15:32:48 rizvi hostapd[7381]: ap@wlan0: STA fe:6e:77:be:8e:f2 IEEE 802.11: disassociated
Sep 16 15:32:50 rizvi hostapd[7381]: ap@wlan0: STA fe:6e:77:be:8e:f2 IEEE 802.11: associated
Sep 16 15:32:52 rizvi hostapd[7381]: ap@wlan0: STA fe:6e:77:be:8e:f2 RADIUS: starting accounting session C68BAA6E40A7E98E
Sep 16 15:32:52 rizvi hostapd[7381]: ap@wlan0: STA fe:6e:77:be:8e:f2 WPA: pairwise key handshake completed (RSN)
```

Note : I am not allowed to use any other interface like eth0 or external wifi module. what should I do now.

Comment: One observation - the procedure you linked WAS NOT designed for Ubuntu and you HAVE NOT explained WHAT YOU DID. You tagged hostapd & systemd-networkd which is incomprehensible!

Comment: what else information should I provide?.